# Programically Determine (in C#) Domain Controller used for authenticating users using Domain Name

Tags: active-directory

How do I Programically determine (using C#) the Domain Controller used for authenticating users using Domain Name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're trying to find out what DC authenticated the current user running your app, you can also look at the LogonServer environment variable - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/77zkk0b6.aspx.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [DomainController](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180939%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) class from the System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory namespace